# Handling the prompts of another Add-In

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

The following code, which is part of an Excel Add-In that I created, will create a file name of the current data extract that we have open.

```
Sub ExtractSave()
'
If InStr(LCase$(ActiveWorkbook.name), "extract") > 0 Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Dim MyDir As String, fn As String
    MyDir = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments") & "\Extract Files" ' change this to valid path
    If Len(Dir(MyDir, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir MyDir
    fn = MyDir & "\Extract - " & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy hh_mm")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fn, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
End If

End Sub
```

When I close the workbook, it does require a save to occur as changes will be made to the workbook. All of this works just fine. The issue is that the company has a .COM Add-In that is required to run on all documents. It labels the document footer with a specific security level identifier. While I do not need to bypass this, I would like to know if it is possible to write code that will replicate hitting enter when this box appears? There are two buttons, **Yes** and **Cancel**. The default button is **Yes** on the popup. I did try adding

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If Me.Saved = False Then Me.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

into the Workbook_BeforeClose private Sub, but the op still appeared. Also, if I am correct, this bit of code will not work for the Saved workbook because this is running from within the Add-In.

I have not been able to find any equivalent information for this particular issue, so any help would be appreciated. Also, I do not know what other information would be useful in your assistance to finding a solution, so please ask and do not down vote because I missed something.

Order of events:

1. Import data into new workbook
2. Run ExtractSave routine
3. See the .COM addin popup (need to have YES button pressed, YES is
   the default button)
4. User performs duties on the workbook
5. Click on close
6. prompted to Save the changes to the workbook (again, default is YES,
   need this "clicked")
7. See the .COM addin popup again(need to have YES button pressed, YES
   is the default button)

What VBA code is available to automatically click on the YES buttons for the .COM add-in while saving the workbook?

Comment: Since it's an internal company addin can you have it changed to include a programmatic interface to allow unattended operation?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. This is a security add-in that cannot be changed, or have changes requested. I wish I could.

Comment: You can use `Application.SendKeys ("~")` . but I don't know where to put it because I didn't understand the question.

Comment: @Fadi Understood. I will edit the OP to show the order of events.

Comment: try to put `Application.SendKeys ("~")` before this line `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fn, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook`

Comment: @Fadi That worked when the first save event (#2 from the list in the OP) occurred, but not when I am closing the workbook. When closing the workbook, I am asked if I want to save changes. When I click on yes, the Popup from the .COM add-in appears again (#6 and #7).

Comment: add another `Application.SendKeys ("~")` before this line `If Me.Saved = False Then Me.Save`

Comment: Sorry, I got the same result.

Comment: @IronMan, I am sorry, I don't have more ideas, `SendKey` itself is a bad idea because it change the status of `NUM Luck`, so wait maybe someone can help.

Comment: Ha ha. I discovered that when I was inputting some data just now. Thanks for what you have provided so far. Good info. I will wait.

Comment: @Fadi There is a fix for the NUMLOCK issue. Anywhere in the code AFTER the 'Application.SendKeys ("~")', just add this line: 'Sendkeys "{NUMLOCK}", True'. This restores the numlock state. I tested this and it works.

Comment: @IronMan, thank you for information, but I think `SendKeys` is not reliable.

Comment: @Fadi Post your comment as an answer and I will accept it for this post. Should have done this awhile ago.

Comment: @IronMan, did you put `SendKeys` in `Workbook_BeforeSave` event to make it work in the second (when close).

Comment: @Fadi I tried it, but it did not work. Not sure why that is. Still looking for a solution to that part, but there does not seem to be any good answer....yet. But following your suggestion of using SendKeys in the first part did work (even though you hate SendKeys).

Comment: @IronMan, I will edit my answer and delete the part #7 and you can leave this question as unanswered maybe someone can help to fix #7 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments:

Adding `Application.SendKeys ("~")` before this line `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fn, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook` worked when the first save event (#2 from the list in the OP) occurred.

And For #7 .COM addin popup, adding `Application.SendKeys ("~")` in `Workbook_BeforeSave` event didn't help (I hope someone can help us to fix it):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

     SendKeys "~"  

End Sub
```

Comment: Hopefully someone can assist with #7 as you said. Thanks for all your assistance!

Comment: @IronMan, You are welcome, and I'm sorry that I couldn't  help with #7.