# Excel VBA SendKeys not working when trying to Send to Excel Add-In

Tags: vba, excel, add-in, sendkeys

**Intro.**: In my company we have a security Add-In installed in Excel, preventing us to save a new Excel workbook without entering the parameters needed.

**Challenge**: use the `SendKeys` to send the keys needed to this Excel Add-In.

**Problem**: when the Add-In screen pops-up (as can be seen in the screen-shot below) the code doesn't seem to continue to this line: `SendKeys " ", True`.

[image: Classification Add-In]

**My Code** (relevant part)

**Edit 1**: The code below is inside a `For` loop, I am exporting a filterred DB for each user to that user. So everytime I try to save a file for one of the users I will encounter the Add-In (I need to **"by-pass"** it inside the `For` loop).

```
' sort the PM's workbook , hide source data    
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
NewWB.Sheets("Combined").Visible = False
NewWB.Sheets("Sheet3").Delete
NewWB.SaveAs "Budget usage - " & Year(Date) & "-" & Month(Date - 30) & " " & PMList(r)

Dim i    As Long

SendKeys " ", True ' <-- it doesn't get to this line when the Excel Add-In pops up
For i = 1 To 3
    SendKeys "+{DOWN}", True
Next i
SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
For i = 1 To 4
    SendKeys "+", True
Next i
SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
```

Comment: Do you have access to the code of the AddIn? Can you change the code, showing the form to `UserForm1.Show vbModeless`?

Comment: @Vityata No, I wish :)

Comment: Does the addin have any public access, so `MyAddIn.` then after the dot  what does intellisense say, can it be set like `MyAddin.Value=ValueToSet`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav it seems not, when I loop thorugh all Add-Ins with `For Each ad In Application.AddIns` it's not there.

Comment: It may be a COM addin written o/s VBA.

Comment: You could take a look at the Application.ComAddins(addinname).connect property setting to false, to maybe stop.

Comment: In this question [Handling the prompts of another Add-In](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34861395/4039286). Adding `SendKeys` **before** `.SaveAs` worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Sub TryMe()

    Dim s           As String
    Dim sPath       As String
    Dim sTitle      As String: sTitle = "runme.vbs"

    s = "Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"")" & vbNewLine & _
        "WScript.Sleep 6000" & vbNewLine & _
        "WshShell.SendKeys ""+{TAB}""" & vbNewLine & _
        "WshShell.SendKeys ""~"""

    CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").createtextfile(sTitle).write s
    sPath = "wscript " & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\runme.vbs"
    Shell sPath, vbNormalFocus

End Sub
```

@Pierre - your idea is to write something like this^^ ?

Then to call it before calling the form and then to delete it somewhere later? Initially I thought that you do not create anywhere the file, but now I have tried it and I noticed. It should work.

Comment: Thanks, took your idea of actualy setting the contents of the VBS inside VBA, and most importatn to keep `vbNormalFocus`

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you launched the  addin popup "froze" the code.
I know no way to do this asynchroneously in VBA (now I began using VB.NET I feel sooooo much better about those things!).
The best i can come up with is:
- save in a temparary file (temp.vbs for ex) some code and run it BEFORE launching the form:

```
Dim s$
s = "Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"")" & vbNewLine & _
    "WScript.Sleep 6000" & vbNewLine & _
    "WshShell.SendKeys ""+{TAB}""" & vbNewLine & _
    "WshShell.SendKeys ""~"""
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").createtextfile(FileName).write s
shell(filename)
```

Comment: I was thinking of the same (but my idea was a bit lamer, to make the script in a separate file and call it from the VBA)!

Comment: @Pierre not sure I fully understand where to put it in a code, this section above is inside a `For` loop, I am saving multiple files for each Project Manager.

Comment: @Vityata : well mine is lame too, just "clean" in that you can remove the VBS after use

Comment: @ShaiRado : you create the VBS file once and for all. Each time you have to press "enter" on a form, before opening the form, you run the VBS. Then after the form is closed, you get into your VBA again

Comment: @Pierre I need to leave for home, will try it later at home (if my kids will let me)

Comment: @Pierre, my idea was manually to create the file somewhere and to refer it each time. In your solution, the vbs file does not exist on the harddrive.

Comment: @vitayata: it is created on the HDD and then removed again. That's why, only slightly less lame :D

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if your addin is sinking the application workbook before save event, so a quick fix to allow saving, would be to sink it again, so in your code, have the following

In a normal module have the following

```
Public cResink As clsResinkApplication
```

Have a class called clsResinkApplication and the code for that class will be as follows

```
Private WithEvents resinkApp As Excel.Application

Public Sub init2(appToResink As Excel.Application)
    Set resinkApp = appToResink
End Sub
Private Sub resinkApp_WorkbookBeforeSave(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "test.xlsx"
End Sub
```

And then in the workbook open you can have the following

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Set cResink = New clsResinkApplication
cResink.init2 Application

End Sub
```

This should divert to your save sink before the addin's one.

Comment: thanks for your help, I ended up using VBScript, but I like to know that I can loop through `AddIns` :)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to thank @Vityata , @Pierre for the idea to do it with VBScript, and also to write the contents of the VBScipt inside the VBA Code.

What I ended up doing is :

**1.** Added the `Call WShellSendKeys` before calling my Save.

```
'========== Call the VBScript to run a Shell to send to Keys in the background ======
Call WShellSendKeys        
NewWB.SaveAs "Budget usage - " & Year(Date) & "-" & Month(Date - 30) & " " & PMList(r)
```

**2.** 
Check if the VBSciprt already exists, if not create it.

```
Public Sub WShellSendKeys()

Dim wsh         As Object
Dim objFile     As Object
Dim objFSO      As Object

Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

If Dir(VBScrPath) <> "" Then  ' <-- VBS file name already exits in folder >> there's no need to re-create it, just run it
    ' Run Shell
    wsh.Run "wscript " & Chr(34) & VBScrPath & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus
Else ' VBS file name doesn't exits in folder >> create it
    Call WriteToVBS
    wsh.Run "wscript " & Chr(34) & VBScrPath & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus
End If

End Sub
```

3.
Another Sub that creates the VBScript with the `SendKeys`.

```
Sub WriteToVBS()

Dim objFile     As Object
Dim objFSO      As Object

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(VBScrPath, 8, True)

' --- Text to write into the VBScript file ---
objFile.WriteLine ("Option Explicit")
objFile.WriteLine ("")
objFile.WriteLine ("Dim WshShell")
objFile.WriteLine ("Dim i")
objFile.WriteLine ("")
objFile.WriteLine ("Set WshShell = CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"")")
objFile.WriteLine ("WScript.Sleep(4000)")
objFile.WriteLine ("")
objFile.WriteLine ("WshShell.SendKeys ""{R}"",True")
objFile.WriteLine ("WScript.Sleep(1000)")
objFile.WriteLine ("For i = 1 To 2")
objFile.WriteLine ("WshShell.SendKeys ""{ENTER}"",True")
objFile.WriteLine ("WScript.Sleep(1000)")
objFile.WriteLine ("Next")

objFile.Close
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing

End Sub
```